# how to optimize xgboost?

Tags: xgboost, hyperparameters

I want to perform hyperparameter tuning for an xgboost classifier. When I use specific hyperparameter values, I see some errors. Please advise the correct way to tune hyperparameters such as
max_feature, criterion, loss, etc

```py
def xgb_grid_search(X,y,nfolds):
    #create a dictionary of all values we want to test
    param_grid = {'learning_rate': (0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.15)
                 }
    # xgb model
    xgb_model=xgb.XGBClassifier()
    #use gridsearch to test all values
    xgb_gscv = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, param_grid, cv=nfolds)
    #fit model to data
    xgb_gscv.fit(X, y)
    return xgb_gscv.best_params_
```

[image: picture.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of wrapping your values in brackets (`'learning_rate': (0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.15)`), use square brackets (`'learning_rate': [0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.05,0.1,0.15]`). Here is an example from [this kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/ozgurb/titanic-work-v1):

```py
def xgb_grid_search(X,y,nfolds):
    #create a dictionary of all values we want to test
    param_grid = { 'max_depth': [4,5,6] , 'min_child_weight':[4,5,6] ,'learning_rate': [0.05,0.1,0.5] ,'n_estimators': [20,50,100] }
    # decision tree model
    xgb_model=XGBClassifier()
    #use gridsearch to test all values
    xgb_gscv = GridSearchCV(xgb_model, param_grid, cv=nfolds)
    #fit model to data
    xgb_gscv.fit(X, y)
    print(xgb_gscv.best_params_)
    print(xgb_gscv.best_estimator_)
    print(xgb_gscv.best_score_)
```

This tutorial provides a fairly comprehensive guide: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/